# fortran 90 recursive subroutines pointer

Tags: pointers, recursion, memory-leaks, fortran, fortran90

I have a subroutine that I would like to be called recursively, but it seems that there is a memory leak when calling it. I've already posted questions on memory leaks in functions

[Fortran 90 function return pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021039/fortran-90-function-return-pointer)

[Fortran 90 difference between compaq visual fortran and gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091998/fortran-90-difference-between-compaq-visual-fortran-and-gfortran/24093581#24093581)

but now I have a new problem. I've switched all of my functions to subroutines, and now I'm having trouble with calling a subroutine recursively. Here is my code (sorry it's not short)

```
   recursive subroutine myCurl3DRTest(d3,u,v,w,gd,n)
     implicit none
     type(vecField3D),intent(inout) :: d3
     real(dpn),dimension(:,:,:),intent(in) :: u,v,w
     type(griddata),intent(in) :: gd
     integer,intent(in),optional :: n
     type(vecField3D) :: temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6
     real(dpn),dimension(:,:,:),allocatable :: dwdy,dvdz
     real(dpn),dimension(:,:,:),allocatable :: dwdx,dudz
     real(dpn),dimension(:,:,:),allocatable :: dvdx,dudy
     real(dpn),dimension(:,:,:),allocatable :: curlx,curly,curlz
     integer :: dummyN
     integer,dimension(3) :: s
     s = shape(u)
     if (.not.present(n)) then 
      dummyN = 1
     else ; dummyN = n ;endif

     call nullifyField(temp1)
     call nullifyField(temp2)
     call nullifyField(temp3)
     call nullifyField(temp4)
     call nullifyField(temp5)
     call nullifyField(temp6)
     call myDel(temp1,w,gd,1,2)
     call myDel(temp2,v,gd,1,3)
     call myDel(temp3,w,gd,1,1)
     call myDel(temp4,u,gd,1,3)
     call myDel(temp5,v,gd,1,1)
     call myDel(temp6,u,gd,1,2)

     allocate(dwdy(s(1),s(2),s(3)))
     allocate(dvdz(s(1),s(2),s(3)))
     allocate(dwdx(s(1),s(2),s(3)))
     allocate(dudz(s(1),s(2),s(3)))
     allocate(dvdx(s(1),s(2),s(3)))
     allocate(dudy(s(1),s(2),s(3)))
     call getY(temp1,dwdy)
     call getZ(temp2,dvdz)
     call getX(temp3,dwdx)
     call getZ(temp4,dudz)
     call getX(temp5,dvdx)
     call getY(temp6,dudy)
     call deleteField(temp1)
     call deleteField(temp2)
     call deleteField(temp3)
     call deleteField(temp4)
     call deleteField(temp5)
     call deleteField(temp6)

     call setX(d3,   dwdy - dvdz  )
     call setY(d3,-( dwdx - dudz ))
     call setZ(d3,   dvdx - dudy  )
     deallocate(dwdy)
     deallocate(dvdz)
     deallocate(dwdx)
     deallocate(dudz)
     deallocate(dvdx)
     deallocate(dudy)
     allocate(curlx(s(1),s(2),s(3)))
     allocate(curly(s(1),s(2),s(3)))
     allocate(curlz(s(1),s(2),s(3)))
     call getX(d3,curlx)
     call getY(d3,curly)
     call getZ(d3,curlz)

     if (dummyN.gt.1) then
        call myCurl3DRTest(d3,curlx,curly,curlz,gd,dummyN-1)
     endif
     deallocate(curlx)
     deallocate(curly)
     deallocate(curlz)
   end subroutine
```

And in the main program, I have

```
   do k=1,10**4
     call myCurl3DRTest(f3,u,v,w,gd,1)
```

!          call myCurl(f3,u,v,w,gd)
       enddo

This, as I mentioned in my previous questions about memory leaks, is causing a memory leak too. Is there something I'm forgetting to allocate? Or are the curlx, curly and curlz not getting deallocated from each level?

Just so it's clear, inside deleteField:

```
   subroutine deleteField(this)
     implicit none
     type(vecField3D),intent(inout) :: this
     if (associated(this%x)) deallocate(this%x)
     if (associated(this%y)) deallocate(this%y)
     if (associated(this%z)) deallocate(this%z)
     this%TFx = .false.
     this%TFy = .false.
     this%TFz = .false.
   end subroutine
```

and inside nullifyField:

```
   subroutine nullifyField(this)
     implicit none
     type(vecField3D),intent(inout) :: this
     nullify(this%x); this%TFx = .false.
     nullify(this%y); this%TFy = .false.
     nullify(this%z); this%TFz = .false.
     this%TFNullified = .true.
   end subroutine
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing based on your previous posts that in your setX (and similar) procedures that you allocate some pointer components of the `d3` object passed as the first argument.  I don't see how those pointer allocations could be matched by a deallocate before the next iteration of the loop or before the nested call to `myCurl3DRTest`.  Depending on what you are trying to do those deallocations could perhaps be provided by calls to `nullifyField`.

If my guess is right then without those deallocations, you would have a memory leak.

A language level of Fortran 95 plus the allocatable TR would make your life so much easier...

Comment: Yeah, it turned out to not deallocating in one of the subroutines.. I would like to migrate to F95, and I may..